# Openlayers ol-ext Add fill color to donut chart

Tags: openlayers

I face the problem to add fill background to donut chart in ol-ext extention of Openlayers
[image]

Any ideas how that can be achieved? I've tried adding fill to image of new Chart, also tried adding text with backgroundFill, but as soon as there is no border radius for Text background it looks very ugly inside cirle of donut.
[image]

Comment: Just check the source of the [demo](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.chart.html).

Comment: I did that, and no possibility to do that, I tried  fill: new Fill({color: '#fff'}) for image as new Chart, I tried adding text inside donut and add fill to text, but it looks very ugly, as far as there is no border-radius for Text in openlayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a style array with a smaller circle on top of the donut:

```
            style = [
              new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Chart({
                  type: 'donut',
                  ...
                  ...
                })
              }),
              new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                  radius: ???,
                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: ???
                  })
                })
              })
            ];
```

Comment: I receive Uncaught TypeError: style.getImage is not a function

Comment: heh, I just made a small error, so yeaaaap it works!!!!!!!! thanks a lot